# How to tell if my company is a non profit organization?

Tags: non-profit

I have recently started working in a publishing company. This is my first job so I did not know what to expect. Neither do I have a clear idea of what I am looking for, although I somewhat know what I do not want (for example, I am sure I do not want to work in a bank or the financial industry). After I started working for about a month, I learned more about myself, one of which is that I do not want to take on a job that 'help the rich get richer'. Hence, I am thinking that I prefer to work in a non-profit organization. I also realized that this is something that I feel strongly about, after I started on my first job. So, I began to search for more information on my current company (which I did not do previously because I do not know what to look for at that time), but I cannot find anything that says that my company is non-profit. Does this mean that my company is a 'for-profit' company? If so, I am seriously considering to find a job at another company.

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: Most organisations are for-profit.

Comment: You're ok working for free, right?

Comment: "Make the rich get richer". They do that with investments. If anything, them creating jobs do not necessarily make them rich. You seem to have some weird chips on your shoulder that you need to deal with.

Comment: There are a lot of non-profit leaders that make a ton of money to run those initiatives.

Comment: A lot of non-profits still “help the rich get richer.” The organization itself may not make profit but that doesn’t mean there aren’t people in upper management with vastly inflated salaries taking advantage of you. I used to do consulting work for non-profits and we would always tell people “non-profit is a tax classification, not a business model.”

Comment: @studoku I have an alternative source of income. If you mean do I need this job to pay the bills the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

The first definition of "company" is

> a commercial business.

So yes, if nothing else is said, *every* company is "for profit".

If you don't want to make the rich richer, there is two ways: you found your own company and decide what jobs you take. Or you check every single organisation you apply to very carefully. Many of the non-profits, while legally being non-profits, still benefit someone rich by being a tax haven or playground for their money.

If you find a non-profit, look up your countries laws and regulations. To reach non-profit tax benefits, in many countries those organisations have to have open books or some kind of public accounting.

For example if you find a company that saves the whales for donations, make sure those donations actually go to saving whales, not to paying their own advertising and board members absurd amounts of money while the whales get two interns that save them on pennies.

If you want to be ethical in that way, it's a lot of work that only you can do yourself.

Comment: I am willing to do all these work on researching on the company/organization, but I am not quite sure where to start. I tried to google 'organization name, financial account' but nothing useful come up. How would you begin the research if you are in my position? Also, is it a good idea to ask my manager directly (if it is non-profit) during our weekly meeting?

Comment: 'if nothing else is said, every company is "for profit"'.  True, but the "something else" might be said in quite an obscure location.  For example, [The Welding Institute](https://theweldinginstitute.com/) is a non-profit company, but one has to dig down to the fifth page of its Articles of Association to find that out.

Answer (score 2):

The default is that a business is for profit. This is why people invest time and/or money into them, despite the risk. Even smaller businesses run by passionate individuals still need to make profit so those passionate individuals can live indoors and eat food.

Most non-profit organisations are charities. They tend to be pretty open about this because of the tax benefits. Non-profit organisations also tend to rely on donations.

If you don't know whether your company is a non-profit, it isn't. Asking will make you look like a buffoon.

Since you don't want to "make the rich richer", you have a few choices when choosing your new job.

1. Charity. Pick a cause you genuinely support. The downside of this is that charities often rely on volunteers and tend to pay below average for skilled work.
2. Public sector- anything that involves working for the government rather than a corporation.
3. Self-employment. Invest time and money in the risk of starting your own business. Run it very badly so you don't make any profit.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it's pretty strange that even after working for a short while for an employer you have no idea whether your employer is a for profit corporation or a non-profit entity. You really don't know how your activities contribute to the product/service your employer is offering and whether that product is sold for a profit, sold below costs or given away?

However I think your second question 'how do I find a job where I don't make the rich even richer' is more interesting, so here are my thoughts about it. I think it's unfortunate that you also rule out banking or the financial industry. Banks and financial institutions do indeed employ a lot of people whose job it is 'to make the rich even richer' as you put it. However there are also a lot of people working in those industries which are taking on those rich bastards. For example people working for compliance in banks or accountants who diligently do their job so companies get properly valued. But maybe the best job someone with your outlook on life could take, is a job at the tax office. I am sure that if you take some iniative and work hard you could make some rich people (significantly) poorer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no desire to make the rich poorer. Neither do I feel a need to take 'revenge' against them. But I like your perspective on this. It makes me think more about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot find anything that says that my company is non-profit. Does
> this mean that my company is a 'for-profit' company?

Not necessarily. It might mean that you don't know where to look.

Most non-profit corporations would mention that fact on their corporate website. But obviously, there's no law or rule requiring them to do so.

If googling isn't working for you, and it's a US corporation, this might help: https://www.upcounsel.com/how-to-find-out-if-an-organization-is-a-nonprofit

(I'm choosing not to speak to your motivation, nor if a non-profit is really what you need.)

Answer (score 0):

A non profit is fairly easy to recognise, things like clubs, religious associations, charities etc,. [Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonprofit_organization)

There's a huge range, so it's quite easy to find them.

> I do not want to take on a job that 'help the rich get richer'.

On some level that is probably unrealistic, many non profits are playgrounds for rich people and useful in indirect ways to strengthening them or their families revenue streams. But they also benefit communities.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend a change in priorities.

Priority 1: You want a company that treats its employees well.
Priority 2: You want a company that treats its customers well.
Priority 3: You want a company that treats its business partners well.
Priority 4: You want a company that makes profit so they can continue supporting your priorities #1 and #2.

At the moment your single priority is much too simple. What would you think about working for a lawyer who makes lots of money by recovering money for fraud victims? Or a company making money by cleaning up environmental damage?

Would you prefer a non-profit company where your boss abuses you on a daily basis, or a for-profit where you enjoy your job and where you can grow personally?